# Moving views along with another view

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout

I have a few buttons on the screen and they all positioned around the main imageview.
Imagine the solar system, it is the same layout. The thing is if I try to make constraints to those buttons everything works just fine until i rotate the device.

the main imageview are centered in the screen and it stays always the same, so i think about moving button's centers along with the imageview center, so they just will moving within imageview center while rotation.

The very best solution would be if the whole process of moving will happen in the willAnimateRotation method.

Comment: Are the views stationary in regards to the main view? So that on rotation they maintain the same position related to the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some screens or a demo project link from which it is more understandable. 
From your statement what I understood, there can be 2 ways:

1. If you want your images and buttons to be of same width and height irrespective of your device orientation, then put every thing in a scrollview and set constraints accordingly. Whenever you will rotating a device call layoutIfNeeded in didRotate or willRotate.
2. If you want your images to be the resized, then put constraints with respect to the margins.

Comment: Here is the screenshot, https://pp.vk.me/c636630/v636630483/3d318/kUG-NrjrvkI.jpg